# Item is moving on mouse click in bootstrap-duallistbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have taken the customized plugin which gives the feature for optgroup which is given over here [Add scroll position return on select1. Add optgroup capability](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/pull/72)

Customized **[bootstrap-duallistbox (with optgroup feature)](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox/pull/72/files)**

I have created a sample example in plunker which shows a running example. The option group is working fine but the issue is that even through when I put **move-on-select="false"** still Item is moving on mouse click.

Can anyone please tell me why this is behaving like that

**[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QRqoTOyWh0ywPNe6jifO?p=preview)**

```
  <select  ng-model="modal.selectedItems"
                       ng-options="item.name group by item.app for item in modal.allItems"
                       multiple
                       bs-duallistbox
                       move-on-select=false
  ></select>
```

Comment: It's `moveOnSelect` not `move-on-select`.
refer the link : http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

Comment: @prakashtank Thanks for the reply, `moveOnSelect: false` is to be mentioned on script side, I have already made that to false in the `jquery.dlbx.js`, still it did'nt work. `move-on-select`is angular directive

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the easiest solution is just to change the implementation of selectGroup. I think it should be this:

```
function selectGroup(e) {
  if(e.data.dlb.settings.moveOnSelect) {
    move(e.data.dlb);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

You'll probably want to make a similar change to `unselectGroup`. The current implementation has strange behavior, where it moves things that aren't selected since it never unselects anything properly.

Edit:

The way that selections are made is faulty. I have no idea of the author's intent, but I suspect this implementation is closer to what a user would expect:

```
function selectGroup(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'OPTGROUP') return;
  $(this).find('option').each(function (index, item) {
    var $item = $(item);
    if (!$item.data('filtered1')) {
      if (!$item.prop('selected')) {
        $item.prop('selected', true);
      } else {
        $item.removeAttr('selected');
      }
    }
  });
  if(e.data.dlb.settings.moveOnSelect) {
    move(e.data.dlb);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Again, make a similar change to `unselectGroup`. In the original code, the problem was that when you click on an individual `option`, the click would bubble up to the `optgroup`, hence the `if` guard. Also, the selection state should not be changed directly. That is already handled in the `move` function. It's much nicer to change the `selected` attribute, which the the `move` function later digests. In this way, it's also visually clear what is actually being selected. Thus, when you click an `optgroup`, it should toggle selected on each the item properties. You may want to modify how the removal of selected attribute is done.

Comment: I have done what you have suggested, now happy to see that mouse click item move issue is resolved, but now the issue is lets say I select one item from the group and then when i click the button to move then the whole group is moving to right. Take a look at this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tdhCTZyvPqmQPZZqj4cQ?p=preview)

Comment: See updated post for a solution to this. This is the first time I've looked at the library, so I don't actually know what the author's original intent is, but this seems most intuitive to me.

Answer (score -1):

Go with

http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

as @prakash Said in Commments.